# Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab. - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I am learning ReactJS and when I am running the code, I am getting this warning:

> "Third-party cookie will be blocked"

and it is coming again and again every second. The number of count of thus warning is increasing continuously. How to remove this warning?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do at all with your app. It's a heads-up by your browser. Click the Issues tab to learn more.